# SQL fiscal periods over multiple years

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, crystal-reports

I am writing a command for Crystal reports in Oracle SQL Dev and i have ran into a problem. My User wants to have parameters that allow them to use a starting year/period in the format 'yyyymm' and ending parameter the same. The problem that i am occuring is that using these param they also want to go from say fiscal year 2012 to 2013 and period 10 (from fiscal year 2012) to period 06 ( from fiscal year 2013) how to setup my command to deal with this? Here is some of the code im currently working on **Tables,views,APIs,etc have had their names changed for security purposes**:

```
SELECT SOO.PART_NO,
   AP.ACCOUNTING_YEAR,
   AP.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD,
   INVENTORY_PART_API.GET_DESCRIPTION(SOO.CONTRACT, SOO.PART_NO)         AS PART_DESCRIPTION,
   SUM(SO.QTY_COMPLETE)                                                           AS QTY_COMP,
   MAX(PART_COST_API.GET_TOTAL_ACCUM_COST(SOO.CONTRACT,SOO.PART_NO,'1','*','*'))  AS TOTAL_ACCUM_COST,       
   MAX(ORA_DATABASE_NAME)                                                         AS ORA_DATABASE_NAME
FROM SHOP_ORDER_OPERATION_TAB SOO
LEFT JOIN ACCOUNTING_PERIOD_TAB AP
   ON SOO.CONTRACT = '09'
   AND SOO.OPER_STATUS_CODE = '90'
   AND SOO.CONTRACT = AP.COMPANY
   AND SOO.LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE BETWEEN AP.DATE_FROM AND AP.DATE_UNTIL 
LEFT JOIN SHOP_ORD SO
   ON SOO.CONTRACT = '09'
   AND SOO.OPER_STATUS_CODE = '90'
   AND SO.ORDER_NO = SOO.ORDER_NO
   AND SO.RELEASE_NO = SOO.RELEASE_NO
   AND SO.SEQUENCE_NO = SOO.SEQUENCE_NO
   AND SO.CONTRACT = SOO.CONTRACT
WHERE SOO.CONTRACT = '09'
   AND SOO.OPER_STATUS_CODE = '90'
   AND NVL(AP.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD,0) BETWEEN SUBSTR('201205',5,2) AND SUBSTR('201306',5,2) 
   AND NVL(AP.ACCOUNTING_YEAR,0) BETWEEN 2012 AND 2013                
GROUP BY SOO.CONTRACT, 
   SOO.PART_NO ,
   AP.ACCOUNTING_YEAR,
   AP.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD
ORDER BY 
   AP.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD ASC,
   AP.ACCOUNTING_YEAR ASC,
  SOO.PART_NO ASC;
```

Comment: I don't really follow--they want 'yyyymm' to represent two things?

Comment: Not really clear on what you're trying to do, but you could use a Crystal Reports formula to adjust the input that you're getting however you need.

Comment: i would however my boss wants most of the work to be done by the command/query itself and as for the 'yyyymm', that just says they are giving a year and fiscal period so example: '201301' year:2013 period: 01(fiscal not calendar ie. not january)

Comment: What's the start of your fiscal year?

Comment: sorry i was on vacation this weekend and didnt get a chance to respond. The fiscal year starts in April starting in 2011 but 2010 and earlier begins at july. This has to be dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of dividing things up by YEAR and MONTH, why not take the supplied YYYYMM and turn them into a proper date so you can use BETWEEN, like:

```
BETWEEN TO_DATE(yyyymm || '01', 'YYYYMMDD') AND LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(yyyymm || '01', 'YYYYMMDD'))
```

last_day returns the last day of the month for any date you feed it, so no fussing with 30 days has september, april, june, and november...

If the crux of your problem is the WHERE criteria:

```
WHERE SOO.CONTRACT = '09'
   AND SOO.OPER_STATUS_CODE = '90'
   AND NVL(AP.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD,0) BETWEEN SUBSTR('201205',5,2) AND SUBSTR('201306',5,2) 
   AND NVL(AP.ACCOUNTING_YEAR,0) BETWEEN 2012 AND 2013
```

Consider combining the last two lines above into:

```
AND TO_DATE(NVL(AP.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD,0) || NVL(AP.ACCOUNTING_YEAR,0) || '01', 'YYYYMMDD') 
    BETWEEN TO_DATE(yyyymm || '01', 'YYYYMMDD') AND TO_DATE(yyyymm || '01', 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Will have to double check the syntax, but the idea is that you turn your YYYYMM into a proper date so that you can use BETWEEN.

Since you aren't comparing an actual date, and BETWEEN is inclusive, you don't need the LAST_DAY function at all.

Comment: Yes, in Oracle it's `BETWEEN TO_DATE(yyyymm || '01', 'YYYYMMDD') AND LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(yyyymm || '01', 'YYYYMMDD'))`.

Comment: the 'mm' is a fiscal period not a month '201301' year:2013 period:01 (fiscal not calendar ie. not january) i just used mm as a place holder sorry that wasnt more specific

Comment: So you don't have a date you can use for comparison?  Is MM a value between 1-12?  It doesn't really matter if 1 is JANUARY.

Comment: mm Is between 1-12 and i have a 'SOO.LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE' that needs to be in the period range. The other dates i have are the date ranges for the periods and the fiscal year.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something very similar to your problem.  What made life so much easier was to combine the fiscal year and period together.

Where you have

```
AND NVL(AP.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD,0) BETWEEN SUBSTR('201205',5,2) AND SUBSTR('201306',5,2) 
AND NVL(AP.ACCOUNTING_YEAR,0) BETWEEN 2012 AND 2013
```

Try this

```
AND NVL(AP.ACCOUNTING_YEAR,0) || NVL(AP.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD,0) BETWEEN '201205' AND '201306'
```

My fiscal years and periods are VARCHARs so the input parameters you have would work.  If your FP is a number, you might have to account for that 0 in the parameter.